# Suppress warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous

Tags: c, security, gcc, gcc-warning, mktemp

How can I suppress following warning from gcc linker:

**warning: the use of 'mktemp' is dangerous, better use 'mkstemp'**

I do know that it's better to use `mkstemp()` but for some reason I have to use `mktemp()` function.

Comment: Use mkstemp instead of mktemp.

Comment: What is the reason that you have to use mktemp?

Comment: you see this warning when compiling bash https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/

Comment: Also compiling recent glibc produces it :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you need the path because you pass it to a library that only accepts path names as argument and not file descriptors or `FILE` pointers. If so you can create a temp dir with `mkdtemp` and place your file there, the actual name is then unimportant because the path is already unique because of the directory.

Comment: You can absolutely STILL use mkstemp: int fd = mkstemp(template); After this call, template will be replaced with the actual file name. You will have the file descriptor and the file's path.

Comment: @Jason Coco you might consider making that an answer, so that it can be upvoted ;-)

Comment: @Jason Coco, ah ok, that sounds reasonable :). I agree with lothar make a answer out of it.

Answer (score 4):

If you **have** to use `mktemp` then there is not anything you can do to suppress that warning short of removing the section that uses `mktemp` from libc.so.6.

Why do you **have** to use `mktemp`?

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

- `mktemp` is not a standard function
- the warning is a special one implemented in the linker as `.gnu.warning.mktemp` section

Use a native OS API if you really need to write to the disk. Or `mkstemp()` as suggested.

Comment: mktemp() is (or was) a standard function. For example in POSIX.1-2001. But don’t use it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mkstemp`:

```
int fd = mkstemp(template);
```

After this call, `template` will be replaced with the actual file name. You will have the file descriptor and the file's path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are statically linking the runtime, then the other option is to write your own version of `mktemp` in an object file. The linker should prefer your version over the runtime version.

**Edit**: Thanks to Jason Coco for pointing out a major misunderstanding that I had in `mktemp` and its relatives. This one is a little easier to solve now. Since the linker will prefer a version in an object file, you just need to write `mktemp` in terms of `mkstemp`.

The only difficulties are cleaning up the file descriptors that `mkstemp` will return to you and making everything thread safe. You could use a static array of descriptors and an `atexit`-registered function for cleanup if you can put a cap on how many temporary files you need. If not, just use a linked list instead.

Comment: @D: It is an error to provide a constant string to mkstemp or mktemp because the library call will attempt to alter the string and you will get a bus fault.

Answer (score 1):

`mktemp` is frequently misused when the one wants
to create a temporary name without actually creating
a tmp file, like `mkstemp` would do. Maybe you want
to pass such name to `sem_open` or `shm_open`, and
you are well aware of an O_EXCL flag. There are many
possible uses, when you want to create some object
with a random name, and that object is not a tmp file.

However, `mktemp` really should not be used, even in
that case. This is because it checks the generated
name over the existing file, and if such file exist,
it generates another name, and so on, in a loop.
This is really not what you want, especially if you
are not going to create such a file at the end.

So it would be better to just write your own
implementation targeting your specific needs, rather
than to try silencing the `mktemp` warning. I simply
extracted the `mktemp` generator code from glibc
sources and added the `%P` modifier handling, which
adds the pid to a template:
https://github.com/dosemu2/dosemu2/blob/devel/src/base/misc/utilities.c#L1103
You can use that code as an example, or just write
your own.

There are just the basic caution rules when doing such
kind of tricks:

- Add pid to the object name, in addition
  to the random chars. That way you avoid a possibility of
  clashing with another instance of your own program which
  has the same fixed part of a template.
- Use O_EXCL when creating an object to avoid any
  possible malicious attempts to make your program to
  open something it shouldn't open.
- If exclusive create failed with EEXIST, an object
  might be stalled (you have pid in the name, and you
  know your pid haven't yet created it), so you can
  unlink it and retry the exclusive creation. If the
  creation fails again then perhaps something malicious
  is going on, so you can just exit.
- Unlink the object as soon as possible, rather
  than on a program exit. After such objects (semaphores,
  shared memory etc) are opened, unlink doesn't prevent
  using them via the already obtained fds. If you want to
  fork the child process that uses these objects, in
  most cases it is enough to open them in a parent only,
  and immediately unlink.
  The child can use them via the inherited fds, rather
  than to open again.

I believe the above recommendations are sufficient
for making the use of your own `mktemp`-alike function
secure and robust. But that's just my own opinion.

Comment: All good points, but IMO even all that isn't necessarily *secure*.  Adding the process PID to a temp name isn't going to make it secure - it's trivial for a malicious actor to get the PID.  Deleting the object if there's a name collision also seems likely to be exploitable in some form for DOS attacks.  Doing this right is **hard**, which is one reasons why I don't like the semantics of `shm_open()` and `sem_open()` - those are prone to TOCTOU-based race conditions and exploits based on the file name.

Comment: Adding the process PID to a temp name isn't going to make it secure - it's needed only to avoid the possibility of clashing with another instance of your own prog, which is an important piece of the puzzle. What makes it secure is O_EXCL, together with the recommendation to never re-open it in a child, but rather use inherited FDs.
Name collision is impossible if you follow all the recommendations, except for the case of an orphaned object and a maliciously created one.

Comment: My concern were directed at the security aspect, especially the possibility of leveraging the delete maliciously.  I haven't been able to come up with a way to exploit that, even for a merely-annoying minor DOS attack, but I probably don't have the creative evil of malware writers.  I apologize for not making the clear in the first comment.

Comment: If you are creating some rather private resource that you are going to share only with the child process by the fork(), and if you have pid in the object name, then delete is entirely harmless, because it only means that the object got orphaned and the pid (that is also in an object's name) got re-used. Consistently dealing with orphaned objects is important, and any scheme must consider the possibility of an orphaned object.